# Unable to load main class that my Procfile is pointing

Tags: java, heroku, procfile

Following is my Procfile

```
web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target\classes;"target\dependency\*"
```

But Im getting the following error when Im running my web app in heroku.

`Error: Could not find or load main class console`

The Main.class is inside the package `info.socket.webmobile`

The application is crashing when I type `heroku open` and it throws the error `Error: Could not find or load main class console` when Im running it like `heroku run java console`

How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: where is the class name in the command?

Comment: wont it fetch the entire class files and detect the corresponding main class when I say `dependency/*` ? if not how can I include my main class that has got its name as Main.class

Comment: `java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target\classes;target\dependency Main.class
`

Comment: ok let me try it. Should include package name as well?

Comment: ok thank you so much. now it doesnt give that error message but it throws other error message like `bash: line 0: fg: no job control
bash: targetdependency: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Procfile` should contain this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* info.socket.webmobile.Main
```

Note that I've add the `info.socket.webmobile.Main` class, and converted the format to a more *nix friendly format.